# calculating scores and total questions asked

Tags: c++

**I'm trying to output the score for each addition, subtraction, multiplication, division in the end test function. and the total of the question asked. 
**Any help would be appreciated**

BTW this is only using local functions and is passing the scores by reference. IT's supposed to output the number of answers that you answer correctly.

Also is there a way where you can prevent the program from letting you select the choices more than once?

**here's what I got so far:**

```
#include < iostream >
#include < iomanip >
#include < stdlib.h >
#include < time.h >
#include < stdlib.h >
using namespace std;



int addition(int addscore);
int subtraction(int subscore);
int multiplication(int multiscore);
int division(int divscore);
int endtest(int & addscore, int & subscore, int & multiscore, int & divscore);
main() {
    int end_final = 0;

    do {

        int addscore, subscore, multiscore, divscore;
        char choice;
        cout << "A- " << "Addition\n";
        cout << "B- " << "Subtraction\n";
        cout << "C- " << "Multiplication\n";
        cout << "D- " << "Division\n";
        cout << "E- " << "End of Test\n";
        cin >> choice;
        cout << endl << endl;

        switch (choice) {

            case 'A':
            case 'a':
                addition(addscore);
                break;


            case 'B':
            case 'b':
                subtraction(subscore);
                break;

            case 'C':
            case 'c':
                multiplication(multiscore);
                break;

            case 'D':
            case 'd':
                division(divscore);
                break;

            case 'E':
            case 'e':
                endtest(addscore, subscore, multiscore, divscore);
                break;
        }
    }
    while (end_final != 1);


    return 0;
}

int addition(int addscore) {
    int iRandom;

    // initialize random seed:
    srand(time(NULL));

    int answer;

    cout << "You have chosen addition\n";
    int randnum1, randnum2;
    int total = 0;


    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        randnum1 = rand() % 15 + 1;
        randnum2 = rand() % 15 + 1;
        cout << randnum1 << " " << "+" << " " << randnum2 << " " << "= ";
        cin >> answer;
        cin.ignore(80, '\n');
        total++;
        if (answer == randnum1 + randnum2) {
            cout << "Correct! \n";
            addscore++;
        } else {
            cout << "Incorrect \n";
        }


    }
}





int subtraction(int subscore) {
    int iRandom;

    // initialize random seed:
    srand(time(NULL));

    int answer;

    cout << "You have chosen subtraction\n";
    int randnum1, randnum2;
    int total = 0;

    while (total != 5) {
        randnum1 = rand() % 20 + 1;
        randnum2 = rand() % 20 + 1;
        if (randnum1 >= randnum2) {

            cout << randnum1 << " " << "-" << " " << randnum2 << " " << "= ";
            cin >> answer;
            cin.ignore(80, '\n');
            total++;
            if (answer == randnum1 - randnum2) {
                cout << endl;
                cout << "Correct!\n ";
                subscore++;
            } else {
                cout << "Incorrect\n ";
            }

        }
    }
}






int multiplication(int multiscore) {
    int iRandom;
    int total = 0;

    // initialize random seed:
    srand(time(NULL));

    int answer;

    cout << "You have chosen Multiplication\n";
    int randnum1, randnum2;


    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        randnum1 = rand() % 20 + 1;
        randnum2 = rand() % 20 + 1;
        cout << randnum1 << " " << "x" << " " << randnum2 << " " << "= ";
        cin >> answer;
        cin.ignore(80, '\n');
        total++;
        if (answer == randnum1 * randnum2) {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Correct! \n";
            multiscore++;
        } else {
            cout << "Incorrect\n ";
        }


    }
}




int division(int divscore) {
    int iRandom;

    // initialize random seed:
    srand(time(NULL));

    int answer;

    cout << "You have chosen Division\n";
    int randnum1, randnum2;

    int total = 0;
    while (total != 5) {

        randnum1 = rand() % 13 + 1;
        randnum2 = rand() % 13 + 1;
        if (randnum1 % randnum2 == 0) {

            cout << randnum1 << " " << "/" << " " << randnum2 << " " << "= ";
            cin >> answer;
            cin.ignore(80, '\n');
            total++;

            if (answer == randnum1 / randnum2) {
                cout << endl;
                cout << "Correct! \n";
                divscore++;
            } else {
                cout << "Incorrect\n ";
            }

        }
    }
}





int endtest(int & addscore, int & subscore, int & multiscore, int & divscore) {
    int total = 0;




    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "Addition" << " " << addscore++ << endl;
    cout << "Subtraction" << " " << subscore << endl;
    cout << "Multiplication" << " " << multiscore << endl;
    cout << "Division" << " " << divscore << endl;
    cout << "Total" << " " << total << endl;

}
```

Comment: You can have another counter for each time the choice is entered. Increment it accordingly and then show the relevant messages.

Comment: Your computation functions never return value. You are incrementing function arguments. Also all scores variables are not initialized, so using them is an undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify the code, declare an *enum*

```
enum { ADDITION=0, SUBTRACTION, MULTIPLICATION, DIVISION };
```

You could have global arrays

```
int used[]  = { 0,0,0,0 }; // not used
int total[] = { 0,0,0,0 }; // total questions per operation
int score[] = { 0,0,0,0 }; // score per operation
```

Then, doing it for 'addition', in the `do {`

```
if ( ! used[ADDITION]) cout << "A- " << "Addition\n";
```

then in the `switch`

```
    case 'A':
    case 'a':
      used[ADDITION] = 1; // tells addition was used
      addition(addscore);
      break;
```

The addition code becomes

```
int addition(int addscore) {
    int iRandom;

    // initialize random seed:
    srand(time(NULL));

    int answer;

    cout << "You have chosen addition\n";
    int randnum1, randnum2;

    total[ADDITION] = 0; // should not be 
    score[ADDITION] = 0; // ...necessary (but in case you call it again)

    for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) { 
        randnum1 = rand() % 15 + 1;
        randnum2 = rand() % 15 + 1;
        cout << randnum1 << " " << "+" << " " << randnum2 << " " << "= ";
        cin >> answer;
        cin.ignore(80, '\n');
        total[ADDITION]++;  // total is incremented for Addition
        if (answer == randnum1 + randnum2) {
            cout << "Correct! \n";
            score[ADDITION]++;  // score is incremented
        } else {
            cout << "Incorrect \n";
        }
    }
}
```

*endtest* becomes

```
int endtest() {

   cout << endl << endl;
   if (used[ADDITION]) cout << "Addition" << " " << score[ADDITION] << " / " << total[ADDITION] << endl;

    // same for SUBTRACTION ... 

    int grandtotal = total[ADDITION] + ....;

    cout << "Grand Total" << " " << grandtotal << endl;

}
```

*endtest* is declared, and called like that

```
int endtest();
...
endtest();
```

---

Since this is C++, you could also make a class Operation, then one subclass per operation, holding the name of the operation and overriding a 'execute' method that does the specific operation, then declare an array of the parent class that holds an instance of each operation ...

---

Based on OP's comments, after the `do {`

```
// initialize variables to zero
int addscore=0, subscore=0, multiscore=0, divscore=0;
```

in the switch

```
    case 'A':
    case 'a':
      used[ADDITION] = 1; // tells addition was used
      addition( &addscore ); // <== gives the pointer to that variable
      break;
```

then in addition code

```
int addition(int *addscore) { // <== gets a pointer
    int iRandom;

    // initialize random seed:
    srand(time(NULL));

    int answer;

    cout << "You have chosen addition\n";
    int randnum1, randnum2;

    total[ADDITION] = 0; // 
    score[ADDITION] = 0; // using your way, this is not necessary anymore

    for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) { 
        randnum1 = rand() % 15 + 1;
        randnum2 = rand() % 15 + 1;
        cout << randnum1 << " " << "+" << " " << randnum2 << " " << "= ";
        cin >> answer;
        cin.ignore(80, '\n');
        total[ADDITION]++;  // total is incremented for Addition
        if (answer == randnum1 + randnum2) {
            cout << "Correct! \n";
            // score[ADDITION]++;  // score is incremented (see above)
            *addscore++; // <== increment variable pointed to by pointer
        } else {
            cout << "Incorrect \n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not really familiar with enum :( is there a way to do this using only local functions??

Comment: You can replace enum with `int ADDITION=0 ; int SUBTRACTION=1 ; ...` which is semantically similar. Local functions? You could add `static` in front of each function declaration if it is what you mean - or is it the use of global variables being the problem?

Comment: @ ringø you seem very knowledgeable in this but I think this program is supposed to be basic. Can I email you to further explain what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: Please try to clarify here within the question, so that everyone sees it and maybe someone else will have a better answer.

Comment: @ ringø basically everything is working in my code, but if I select end test without running through the other selections, the subtraction and division are not initialized at 0 for some reason. so when I go to add up the scores of each  selection, it is giving me a weird result

Comment: @ ringø The addition and multiplication functions seem to work fine. It is just division and subtraction... I think it has to do with the while loop I used

Comment: @ ringø i didn't do that in the addition function but it works. I used a for loop to generate random nums for addition and multiplication. I used a while loop for division and subtraction but it seems to be messing up the scores.